# Facing this error : An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

Tags: c#

i just start to learn this, when i run, i face this error in this line of code :  int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString()); Additional information: Invalid column name 'Employer'.

Full Code :

```
public partial class Registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(IsPostBack)
      {
          SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
          conn.Open();

          string checkuser = "select count(*)from Employer where Employer='" + TextBoxEUsername.Text + "'";
          SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
          int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
          if (temp == 1)
          {
              Response.Write("Username Existed, Please Choose another Username.");

          }
          conn.Close();
      }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            string insertQuery = "insert into Employer(EUsername, EPassword, Name, Contact_Number, Email, Company_Name, Current_Position) values (@EUN, @EPas, @Name, @ConNumber, @Email, @ComName, @CurPos)";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EUN",TextBoxEUsername.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EPas",TextBoxEPassword.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",TextBoxEName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConNumber",TextBoxEContactNumber.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",TextBoxEEmail.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConName",TextBoxECompanyName.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurPos",TextBoxECurrentPosition.Text);

            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Response.Redirect("Manager.aspx");
            Response.Write("Registration Successful");
            {
                Response.Write("Username Existed, Please Choose another Username.");

            }
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
            {
        Response.Write("Error:"+ ex.ToString());
            }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your sql query is correct?

Comment: Dont you mean `select count(*)from Employer where EUsername=` ???

Comment: Are you sure you have a `Employer` column in your `Employer` table? Maybe you wanna use `EUsername` instead.

Comment: am i the only one who thinks this whole class is wrong, sql in codebehind.... really??

Comment: Sorry careless mistake for not realizing that, thanks Leppie and Soner Gonul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to handle the exception you should have a try/catch block implemented in the top half of your code. Something like...

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(IsPostBack)
  {
try
    {
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ERegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
      conn.Open();

      string checkuser = "select count(*)from Employer where Employer='" + TextBoxEUsername.Text + "'";
      SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
      int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
      if (temp == 1)
      {
          Response.Write("Username Existed, Please Choose another Username.");

      }
    }
catch (Exception e)
    {
//Add your own handling of the Exception here
    }
finally
    {
      conn.Close();
    }
  }
```

}

Though you may also want to consider the SQL connection being part of a Using block.

However in answer to WHY you are getting the exception, it sounds like the column Employer does not exist in the table Employer in your database, if you are getting the message 'Invalid column name 'Employer'"

I would suggest that even if you correct that you should still have exception handling as SQL often produces transient errors such as connection failures, even if you get everything right in your code, which will need handling.